# Customise Banner In spring Shell 2

Tags: banner, spring-shell

I have used spring Shell 1.x.  It provided provision for customise the banner. I am not trying to use Spring shell 2 and trying to do that same but i cannot  finding the class.

Document also does not speak about it. Do any body know how to customise the same?

Answer (score 2):

Banner is now the responsibility of Spring Boot, as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-shell/docs/2.0.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#_let_s_give_it_a_ride). Just drop a `banner.txt` file in your resources and it should be picked up